How do I remove the leading space in an Excel cell having imported from Confluence
I've looked at similar questions but haven't managed to find an answer.
In a Confluence space, I went to Space Settings > Manage Space > Export Space > PDF. I then selected the "Select what to export" radio button which showed me a tree structure view of the space.
Instead of exporting to PDF, I just copied that tree structure and put it into Excel (as I was really just after a list of existing pages to work with).
There's a leading space at the start of every cell that I can't seem to get rid of. It is removed by a simple find and replace, but that also removes the spaces between words which I don't want to keep. I've tried the following but none of them remove the leading space:
=TRIM(A1)
=TRIM(CLEAN(A1))
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),""))
=TRIM(CLEAN((SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),""))))

I've also tried removing all the hyperlinks in case that was the issue and then retried the above trims but this didn't work either.
Any ideas??

Thanks, yeah I meant to say I did also try that in isolation and not just as part of TRIM but it didn't seem to do anything.
I just can't figure why a simple find and replace removes if but then it isn't recognised by TRIM or SUBSTITUTE!

You could try find the offending character code using --> =CODE(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)) something which is not known to you, will help you to detect, and remove after using SUBSTITUTE()

It is definitely a 160 - if you use =CODE(MID(a1,1,1)) that's what it says.  But when I use the four things above the last two do work.  So =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")) does what you want with my export on my excel.  That means something is different between our machines.

Thanks both, identification of the character did it. I missed an important bit of info from my question, I'm on a Mac! I hadn't realised the character sets were different and a quick search told me the nbsp on a Mac is 202, so that sorted it. Thanks :-)

When editing the hyperlink, you can see the leading space in "Text to display". That may be why TRIM etc. do not work.
=REPLACE(cell,1,1,"") seems to work though, not sure whether it is applicable for your purpose.
BTW, it seems to be a 'regular' space (U+0020).
